# cwac-endless not stop appending on data ready

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm ussing cwac endless in a subcustom android with asynchttp library, and a listView in a fragment, when I execute the webservices, and notify the onReady data throw the listener (as the example), the onbackground task is executed otherwise until the max items are achieved. Some body have an idea what is happening? thanks in advance

Comment: to be honest, I didn't get at all what are you trying to ask :( Is there any chance you can rephrase your question?

Comment: Or better yet, provide a minimal program that demonstrates the problem.